Is there any advantage in reading query results in blocks?
I have an Entity Framework query that can return ~ 10,000 rows. This is used to populate a map with pins.
Is there a way to get the results back in blocks that will be as fast as reading everything at once? For example, if I do:
.OrderBy(e => e.Id).Skip(offset).Take(1024)

And read the results back 1K at a time, is that in total, about the same amount of time as reading everything all at once? Or is there another way to do this?
Note, this is not a case of a paged grid where I can make a single call of .Skip(x).Take(pageSize) and that one call is sufficient until they go to another page. In this case I do need all the results.

"And read the results back 1K at a time, is that in total, about the same amount of time as reading everything all at once?" - have you tried to measure it? What is the problem to read everything at once?

Also based on the database used it might be beneficial to use Where(e => e.Id > maxIdFromPreviousBatch) instead of Skip(offset) but you should measure it for your concreate case.

Use Keyset pagination

@GuruStron I learned a long time ago that correctly benchmarking DB access is very very difficult to get right. So I ask in the hope that people who do know how to do this right have determined if in most cases if there's an advantage to reading in blocks. thanks

@DavidThielen I don't have enough experience here to give a complete answer (and you have not even tagged the database you are using which can be a huge factor) but if you don't expect to have much more than 10k of records - just load them in one query and then see if your app actually has any problems. Other than that without knowing actual setup (database used, schema, data size, load profiles, transactions used) it would be really hard to tell.

Retrieving data in chunks will always be slower and use more resources than fetching the whole thing at once, but when you can support your queries with the right indexes the difference is small enough. On the other hand, paging has the advantage that you don't consume all your resources all at once. Think of buying things in installments vs pay it all at once.

This question has a curious way of looking like a X & Y Problem, why not tell the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of going around it like cat around a glass of milk. If you're looking for "even" performance, why do you want to split in smaller batches, especially if you still want to display all results eventually. For raw SQL Server perspective, doing multiple OFFSETs rather than a single large one are likely gonna be bad because OFFSET queries are hard on indexes (that's why keyset pagination was suggested)

The biggest impacts on performance and resource usage would be best case to ensure you are using projection (Select()) to retrieve just the values you need, or using an AsNoTracking() query if you do need to load entities. These both ensure EF doesn't bother reading or adding to the tracking cache.
Loading 10k rows of Ids, coords, and maybe a name/label for instance to populate a map area should be no issue to do in one hit if you need all 10k items. Paginating results is more about only needing to display a page of values at a time. If you need 10k items, loading them 1k at a time won't save resources or time. Updating 10k items (if you cannot batch the operation) can save resources by only loading/tracking a subset at a time, so long as you purge the tracking cache between pages.
